# markerWithLabel in googleMaps causes Infowindow to be displayed faraway from markerClick

Tags: google-maps, marker, infowindow

I am using markerWithLabel.js for my custommarkers and when ever i was clicked on the marker, the infowindow is displayed a little far away distance from my marker location.[image]

Here is my code markerCode:

```
 var t = this;

 var m = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latlng,
        draggable: true,
        raiseOnDrag: true,
        icon: ' ',
        map: t.map.map,
        labelContent: '<i class="fa fa-circle fa-2x"  style="color:#8dc73f;height:22px;width:22px;"></i><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="transform: rotateZ(9deg);margin-top: 5px;"></i><i style="position:relative;margin-left:-19px;" class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>',
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
        labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
        labelStyle: { opacity: 0.75 }
    })
```

and infoWindow

```
   t.popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: popup, closeButton: false, maxWidth: 365, maxHeight: 300, position: latlng});

    google.maps.event.addListener(m, 'click', function() {
        var content = _.template(CheckinTemplate, t.markerTemplateData(t.get('checkin')));
        t.popup.set('content', content);
        t.popup.open(t.map.map, m);
    });
```

Is there any issue with this, even if i do for simple custom markers the same issues i ma facing with markerWithLabel js

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including a copy of the icon image.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleauto/zphbt36L/   Please check here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have an icon for your labelled marker.

```
icon: ' ',
```

So the API won't be able to compute the correct `pixelOffset` when using:

```
infowindow.open(map, this);
```

Set the position of the infowindow instead and use the single parameter version of [InfoWindow.open](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#InfoWindow)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(e) {
  infowindow.setContent('Marker postion: ' + this.getPosition());
  infowindow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
  infowindow.open(map);
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zphbt36L/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var globalMarker = [];
var map;

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4214, -75.6919);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: center,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var markers = [];


  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat() + Math.random() - 0.5, center.lng() + Math.random() - 0.5);
    //var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.4214, -75.6919)
    marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
      position: latLng,
      draggable: true,
      raiseOnDrag: true,
      map: map,
      icon: ' ',
      labelContent: '<i class="fa fa-circle fa-2x" style="color:#8dc73f;height:22px;width:22px;"></i><i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-stack-1x fa-inverse" style="transform: rotateZ(9deg);margin-top: 5px;"></i><i style="position:relative;margin-left:-19px;" class="fa fa-circle-o fa-2x"></i>',
      labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(45, 0),
      labelClass: "labels", // the CSS class for the label
      labelStyle: {
        opacity: 0.75
      }
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    makeDiv(i, 15, "Marker #");
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent('Marker postion: ' + this.getPosition());
      infowindow.setPosition(this.getPosition());
      infowindow.open(map);
    });
  }
  var clusterOptions = {
    zoomOnClick: false
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);
  globalMarker = markers.slice();
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {
    var content = '';

    // Convert lat/long from cluster object to a usable MVCObject
    var info = new google.maps.MVCObject;
    info.set('position', cluster.center_);

    //----
    //Get markers
    var markers = cluster.getMarkers();

    var titles = "";
    //Get all the titles
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      titles += markers[i].labelContent + "\n";
    }
    //----


    infowindow.close();
    infowindow.setContent(titles); //set infowindow content to titles
    infowindow.open(map, info);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close()
    });

  });
}

function makeDiv(index, zoomLevel, content) {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML += '<div onclick="zoomIn(' + index + ',' + zoomLevel + ')">' + content + ' ' + index + '</div>';
}

function zoomIn(index, zoomLevel) {
  map.setCenter(globalMarker[index].getPosition());
  map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
 html,
 body,
 #map {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%
 }
 .labels {
   color: red;
   background-color: white;
   font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Arial", sans-serif;
   font-size: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   width: 90px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r315/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel_packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleauto/zphbt36L/5/ i added some text(<div><span>) to the labelContent along with fontawesome icons. Even If i click on that text the infoowindow will display at marker location. I want only if i click on the fontawesome icon, then the infoWindow has to display. If i clicked on the textContent, I dont want display infoWindow. Please guide on this

Comment: That is a different question (there were no icons in this question).  If my answer solved your original question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), then ask a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you as per the Question your answer is working fine and i accepted your answer

Comment: jsfiddle.net/jsfiddleauto/zphbt36L/5 i added some text(<div><span>) to the labelContent along with fontawesome icons. Even If i click on that text the infoowindow will display at marker location. I want only if i click on the fontawesome icon, then the infoWindow has to display. If i clicked on the textContent, I dont want display infoWindow. This issue i am facing , Is it possible to do with markerwithlabel .Libaray

Comment: thank you, I have done it ,, after clicking on marker first check, if (event.target.localName === 'span') { retrun;}